# CSS type selector overrides attribute selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

Generally speaking, an attribute selector has higher specificity than a type selector, but in the image below, the type selector wins (`margin` is set to `0`)?

Is it because user agent stylesheet (browser default style) always gets overridden by custom CSS regardless of CSS specificity?

[image]

Comment: instead of a screenshot share a code that reproduce this so we can better see.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: "Is it because user agent stylesheet (browser default style) always gets overridden by custom CSS regardless of CSS specificity?" Yes. The concept in the cascade that's relevant here is the [origin](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#cascade)

Comment: @Alohci If you could post that as an answer, the OP could accept it.

Comment: @TylerH: It's not possible to provide one given that part of the code that's required is coming internally from the UA. A Stack Snippet with just the button, input, optgroup, select, textarea CSS rule by itself is not terribly clear as an MCVE as readers would still need to do the manual work (God forbid) of opening their Chrome dev tools. Alternatively it could include the UA styles ahead of the author styles to simulate the cascading order, but *that would not even be Verifiable* because then you're just comparing two author-level rules.

Comment: A reasonable compromise is to add alt text to this image, but I doubt Markdown supports line breaks in HTML image alts, so we'd need something other than the typical "transcription" approach to images of text/code.

Comment: @BoltClock The request was mostly in the vein of posting code as code instead of as screenshots, IIRC, not a stack snippet of something runnable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because user agent stylesheet (browser default style) always gets overridden by custom CSS regardless of CSS specificity?

Yes. The technical name for "custom CSS" is author-level CSS as detailed in [this section of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#cascade). Specificity is only relevant when you're comparing two CSS rules that have the same origin, either two UA styles or two author styles.